# Init CXF Soap client in Spring : @Configuration or @Service?

Tags: spring, soap, cxf

What is the proper location to initialize a SOAP client (created with CXF) ?

- Using a @Configuration, with a @Bean method returning the stub ? OR
- Initialize the connection with a singleton instance inside a @Service class ?

Comment: I don't think that there is a best practice for this. Both will work. If it's just one bean I would put it in @Configuration class.

Comment: I've finally used a @Service class to manage the soap connection